# Field Type Date invalid when run in Python, but not in Model?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, feature-class, date, field-mapping

Using ArcGIS Desktop Advanced 10.1 and PyScripter

When running the arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion, I get the error that the field type of Date is not valid.  However, when running this same procedure in the model where the python was exported from, it runs successfully.
I have verified that the field type is in fact Date for the field and that the field length is sufficient.
This seeems to be an issue after moving to 10.1

Error Message:

```
ExecuteError: ERROR 000278: Field Mapping error: Field type invalid for output field xxx and input field xxx
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post the Python code that leads to this error, please?  Just enough so that we can see what parameter values are being submitted to FeatureClassToFeatureClass.

Comment: Could you provide the Python code that you are trying to run?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem after upgrading to v10.1 for nearly the same scenario... errors on Date columns when using arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion with joined layers in Python script.

I'm using the following workaround:

1. Use arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion, but omit the field map parameter. I'm storing the output feature class in a temporary file geodatabase. For example:

   ```
   arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(joinedLayersSource, "C:/gisdata/D_Properties.gdb", "tempFeatureClass")
   ```

   This basically dumps the joined layers into a single feature class in the file geodatabase with all attributes from all joined layers.
2. Do another arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion using the feature class that was output from the previous step. Here, you can specify the field map parameter to include the attributes that you want in your output feature class as well as rename attributes.

   ```
   arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion("C:/gisdata/D_Properties.gdb/tempFeatureClass", "C:/gisdata/D_Properties.gdb", "Properties", "", """PARCEL_CODE "Parcel Code" true true false 12 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:/gisdata/D_Properties.gdb/tempFeatureClass,tempFeatureClass.PARCEL_CODE,-1,-1;LEGAL_DESC "Legal Description" true true false 12 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:/gisdata/D_Properties.gdb/tempFeatureClass,tempFeatureClass.LEGAL_DESC,-1,-1""", "")
   ```

Yes, I know this isn't exactly elegant, but it was the only way I could figure out how to work around this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am also getting the same error.

I have a fc1 with a date field
Join a fc2 to fc1
Export to fc3
I get the ERROR 00278 error but only when running it from python.

This error is new since we moved to arcgis 10.1.

FYI if I remove the date field it works.
If I have no join it works.
only seems to be an error with a fc that has a date field and joined to another fc and exported fc to fc

Answer (score 0):

This error was coming up in Python using 10.1 just as Mark and Stephanie described:  Exporting a joined feature class failed when a date field was included.

However due to the fact I am working in file geodatabases, I was able to get around the error by replacing the "Feature Class to Feature Class" tool in the model with the "Feature Class to GeoDatabase (multiple)" tool.  When exported to Python, it seems to run without the error described.

This doesn't solve the problem, but it at least is a workaround.